# problem with more than one datasheet views on SharePoint 2013 page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, view, datasheet

I have a problem with the datasheet views on SharePoint 2013. 
When I add more than one datasheet on a page I have some troubles with choice fields.  When I try to select a value on the choice field on the second datasheet view the select button is positioned on the choice field on the first datasheet view. 
Do you have any idea about this problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to **the browser**, not SharePoint . Specifically, occurs when you use a `google chrome`

[image]

So to overcome this issue try to use `Internet Explorer` where it will work properly as shown below

[image]